# Iterate over an array and add additional information to its items in PHP

Tags: php

I have a following `items` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Item no 1
            [created] => 2016-05-11 16:51:15

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Item no 2
            [created] => 2016-05-11 17:02:27

        )
)
```

What I need to do is to iterate over the array and a value to it. For the sake the sake of simplicity let's I want to add `status` which is equal to `1`.

I have creted this simple foreach, however the status is not being added:

```
foreach( $items as $item ){

   $item['status'] = '1';

}
```

How could I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reference &$item

```
foreach($items as &$item ) {
   $item['status'] = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in the past, this should do it:

```
foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
    $items[$key]['status'] = '1';
}
```